# How to make my sprite kit scene appear above a UIView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiimageview, sprite-kit

I've done some searching but haven't found anything directly addressing my issue: I have an `SKScene` with several `SKNodes` each with `SKSpriteNode` objects for my game, and I am using a background `UIImageView` (there are some things I need to do with background that cannot be reasonable done with sprite kit - to my knowledge at least); the problem I'm having is that the `UIImageView` appears above everything and I can't see my game objects.

In my view controller (.m file) I have the following code to call my scene

```
@implementation GameViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    SKView * skView = (SKView *)self.view;

     SKScene * scene = [GameScene sceneWithSize:skView.bounds.size];
    scene.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleModeAspectFill;
    [skView presentScene:scene];

}
```

In the `GameScene` above, I have several `SKNodes` where all my game objects are children of (for example `nodeHDU`, `nodePlay`, `nodePauseMenu`...), and I am using a `UIImageView` as my background (I am switching between background scenes over time and am using some nice transitions such as `UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve;` couldn't accomplish this with a `SKSpriteNode` as background without using multiple `SKSpriteNodes` and an intricate array of `SKActions` so I"m using `UIImageView`)

```
UIView *backgrounds = [[UIView alloc] init];
[self.view insertSubview:backgrounds belowSubview:self.view];

UIImageView *imageBackground = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,self.view.frame.size.width,self.view.frame.size.height)];
[backgrounds addSubview:imageBackground];
[backgrounds sendSubviewToBack:imageBackground];
[imageBackground setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"1-A.png"]];
imageBackground.alpha=1.0;
```

However, the `ImageBackground` above is the only thing I see when running the app in Xcode. The other objects from my game (children of other nodes) exist, and various `NSLog` statements are getting called, but they seem to appear behind the `ImageBackground` I have. The code above "belowSubview" and "sendSubviewToBack" don't help.

So How can I send the `imageBackground` to actually be the background?

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is here that you are directly setting `SKView` as a controller view. To overcome from this issue don't make `self.view` a type of `SKView`. Do the following step in your storyboard or Xib :

1. Add an `UIImageView` on the controller's view first. Set the image as well.
2. Then add a `SKView` over the `UIImageView`and set `UIClearColor` to the background colour.

So the complete hierarchy is like `UIViewController`->`UIView`->`UIImageView`->`SKView`